# how to deregister a stream when all I have is ChannelHandlerContext

Tags: netty

Is there a way to deregister the reads in netty with the ChannelHandlerContext object?

how does one deregister for reads?  Our system is getting backed up and need the local nic buffer to fill up (which will cause the remote one to fill up which slows down the client until we can process more data from that socket).

Any ideas on how to use that object to deregister for reads?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

ah there it is....

ctx.getChannel().setReadable(true);