# In netty, how to unregister for reads my channel from the selector temporarily

Tags: netty

Under pressure from a certain client, we would like to unregister for reads on a certain client and when doing that our incoming nic buffer fills up and then his outgoing fills up and we stop consuming data.

In netty, how do I unregister for reads (and then re-register once it is all stable again).

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748888/how-to-deregister-a-stream-when-all-i-have-is-channelhandlercontext?rq=1) question of you the same? `ctx.getChannel().setReadable(false);` turns reads off, and `ctx.getChannel().setReadable(true);` turns them back on again

Comment: duplicate with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060454/how-to-pause-and-resume-reading-with-netty-4?